# TapeEquilibrium implementation

Tags: c#, performance, programming-challenge

I took a test at [Codility](http://codility.com) called *TapeEquilibrium*. The task description that I received can be seen [here](http://i.gyazo.com/c928bbdb24e58548c1a64193c83025da.png).

I came up with a solution that worked, and I was pretty happy with. However, the performance was apparently awful. The expected time complexity is apparently supposed to be \$O(N)\$, but I got \$O(N * N)\$. I'm not quite sure what exactly that means, but I've heard about it several times.

I'd like some help on improving my solution and get information about what I did wrong and how it could be done better, and why. I'm doing this to learn and improve.

```
public int solution(int[] A) {
    int min = Int32.MaxValue;
    for (int i = 0; i < A.Length - 1; i++) {
        // p = i + 1            
        int part1 = 0, part2 = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) part1 += A[j];
        for (int j = i + 1; j <= A.Length - 1; j++) part2 += A[j];

        int val = Math.Abs(part1 - part2);
        if (val < min) min = val;
    }
    return min;
}
```

Comment: Hi! I removed the off topic part of your question. You might want to try asking that on Programmers, but I'm not 100% sure it's on topic there. Please be sure to visit [their help center](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before posting there.

Comment: See [Plain English explanation of Big O](http://stackoverflow.com/q/487258/1157100).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two unnecessary inner loops in your implementation. I think you could calculate the minimal difference via 2 not nested loops.
You don't need to calculate sums of parts on each iteration via loops, the idea is to modify sums by moving 1 array's element form one part to another on each iteration.
The following approach gives a [time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) of \$O(N)\$:

```
public int solution(int[] A)
{
    // Sum of parts in the initial position:
    int part1 = A[0];
    int part2 = A.Sum() - part1;  // 1st loop
    int min = Math.Abs(part1 - part2);

    // Initial position is 1 since parts must be non-empty.
    // Looping should be finished before the last element for the same reason.
    for (int i = 1; i < A.Length - 1; i++)  // 2nd loop
    {
        int a = A[i];
        // Move current element from part2 to part1:
        part1 += a;
        part2 -= a;
        // Find the difference:
        int val = Math.Abs(part1 - part2);
        if (val < min)
        {
            min = val;
            // Early exit condition:
            if (min == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return min;
}
```

**EDIT**
Added early exit condition `part1 >= part2`, thanks to @Heslacher.
**EDIT 2**
Removed early exit condition `part1 >= part2`, since array elements can be negative.
**EDIT 3**
Since parts must be non-empty, loop limits should be deflated by `1`. Thanks again to @Heslacher.
**EDIT 4**
Fixed initial iteration. Thanks to @Timo.

Comment: Where do you compare a[0] to the rest? You immediately add to part1 and subtract from p2.

Comment: @Timo Nice catch! Fixed. Thank you.

Comment: ok, you start from the left, Heslacher starts from the middle. I think it does not matter where to start. Could you have a look at the comments of heslacher's post, his code and give a hint if you can? `[4,2,1,2]` does not give the correct result for his code.

Answer (score 7):

**Style**

Initializing of multiple variables on one line **removes readability**.
Writing `for` loops on one line **removes readability**.

Dead code should be deleted (`// p = i + 1`)

<s>**Bug**</s>

It seems that you have a little unnoticed bug in your code. Your loop

> ```
> for (int i = 0; i < A.Length - 1; i++) {
> ```

misses the last element of your array.

**Problem**

Let us assume we have an array `A` containing 8 elements like

3 5 7 2 5 2 1 3

The ideal divider would be if the arrays left half summed up would be equal to the right half summed up.
Unfortunatetly here

sumLeft = A[0] + A[1] + A[2] + A[3] == 17
sumRight = A[4] + A[5] + A[6] + A[7] == 11
difference = sumLeft - sumRight == 6

So as we see that the left half `>` right half let us take the last element of the left side and check if `2 * A[half-1] <= difference` wich is `2 * 2 <= 6` so we can do

sumLeft = sumLeft - A[3] == 15
sumRight = sumRight + A[3] == 13
difference = difference - 2 * A[3] == 2

Or simplified for `sumLeft > sumRight`

```
difference = sumLeft - sumRight;
while (2*A[currentHalf-1] <= difference)
{
    currentHalf = currentHalf -1;
    sumLeft = sumLeft - A[currentHalf]
    sumRight = sumRight + A[currentHalf]
    difference = difference - 2 * A[currentHalf];
}
```

**EDIT : Based on @Dmitry's comments I rechecked the algorithm and came to the result that this algorithm only works for positive numbers.**

And my implementation of the above

```
public int solution(int[] A)
{
    int length = A.Length;
    int sumLeft = 0;
    int sumRight = 0;

    int currentArrayHalf = length / 2;

    for (int i = 0; i < currentArrayHalf; i++)
    {
        sumLeft = sumLeft + A[i];
        sumRight = sumRight + A[i + currentArrayHalf];
    }

    Boolean isEven = length % 2 == 0;

    if (!isEven) { sumRight = sumRight + A[length - 1]; }

    int step = 1;
    if (sumLeft > sumRight)
    {
        step = -1;
        if (isEven)
        {
            currentArrayHalf--;
        }
    }

    int difference = Math.Abs(sumLeft - sumRight);
    if (difference == 0) { return difference; }

    while (currentArrayHalf >= 0 && currentArrayHalf < length && 2 * A[currentArrayHalf] <= difference)
    {
        sumLeft = sumLeft - A[currentArrayHalf];
        sumRight = sumRight + A[currentArrayHalf];
        difference = difference - 2 * A[currentArrayHalf];
        currentArrayHalf = currentArrayHalf + step;
    }

    return difference;
}
```

Comment: I translated the code to [python](https://github.com/tik9/ml/blob/master/te.py), but it is not working regarding the correct diff. Can you have a close look?

Comment: I got this driver: `[4,2,1,2]`. 6>3, currentHalf=Pos. 2. If you switch the CurrentH to Pos. 1, you have the right separation: 4<5. But 2*2 is not < diff (=3), so you do not enter `while`.Tschüss.

Comment: .. and [here](https://github.com/tik9/ml/blob/master/te.java) is a java working example. So, my conclusion for small array sizes is using 2 inner loops as seen [here](https://github.com/tik9/ml/blob/master/te2.py), second function. But what about huge arrays..

Comment: @Timo, unfortunately I don't have the time right now to dig into this. Feel free to change the code in my answer.